# Environmental variable

Tags: environment-variables

I am newly for Ubuntu and I just downloaded `mulval` software packet to run it on my Ubuntu, but I still not clear that the instruction say this:

> "The environmental variable MULVALROOT should point to this
>   package's root folder
>
> ```
> Include $MULVALROOT/bin and $MULVALROOT/utils in PATH"
> ```

I installed mulval in my home directory:

```
worravit@worravit-Aspire-5715Z:~/mulval$
```

I read some questions in this community but those of them differences from mine.

Could anyone give me clear instruction please?

Answer (score 0):

In this case `~/mulval` is mulval's root folder.

Edit your `.profile` file (run `gedit ~/.profile`) and add the following lines in the end:

```
# set variables for mulval
MULVALROOT="$HOME/mulval"
PATH="$MULVALROOT/bin:$MULVALROOT/utils:$PATH"
```

Save the file then log out and log in.